# How to generate HTML from Array Items?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this javascript code, to filter search items but i want to filter a div element not just plain text.

```
var searchBox = document.querySelector("input");
var resultList = document.getElementById("resultList");
var resultsArray = [
"Walt Disney",
"Which color do you like?",
"Where are we?",
"Which wells are the best?",
"Who's on first?",
"Cowboys wear white",
"Wells are awesome!",
"Whoooppppeeeeee",
"Which Witch is Which",
"What's going on?",
"Well look at that!"
];


searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
var searchTerm = searchBox.value.toLowerCase();

// reset ul by removing all li items
while (resultList.hasChildNodes()) {
    resultList.removeChild(resultList.lastChild);
}

// loop through array of sentences
for (var i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++) { 
    // if the array item starts with the search value AND the input box is not empty
    if(resultsArray[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm) && searchTerm != "") {
        var li = document.createElement('li'); // create an li item
        li.innerHTML = resultsArray[i]; // add the sentence to the new li item
        resultList.append(li); // add new li item to resultList ul
    }
}

// if resultList is empty after going through loop display 'no results found'
if (!resultList.hasChildNodes() && searchTerm != "") {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "no results found";
    resultList.append(li);
}
});
```

i want to change var resultsArray items to div class items for example: "Walt Disney", to

```
 <div class="item"><a href="walt-disney.html"><img src="images/walt-disney.png" alt="walt disney" border="0" /></a>walt disney</div>
```

Comment: Like a linked list?

Comment: Where do the URLs `walt-disney.html` and `images/walt-disney.png` come from?

Comment: And what does `li` elements have to do with your desired output?

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's apparently a simple search engine, the LI is the list of results.

Comment: Can you provide the full html as well? With that would be easy to put my solution in a jsfiddle code runner

Comment: <div class="page">
  <form>
         <input type="text" name="search"/>
     </form>
     <ul id="resultList"></ul>
            </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Stop creating, appending, and deleting `HTMLElement`, it's a hassle

To avoid tons of `for` loops and using `document.createElement`, `.appendChild`, and `.removeChild`. I would suggest using `.innerHTML`. Along with this, there is no need to rewrite the list of items in `resultArray` as an object, just modify the strings to match each attribute's requirements, like so:

**JavaScript Code:**

```
const searchBox = document.querySelector("input");
const resultList = document.getElementById("resultList");
const resultsArray = [
  "Walt Disney",
  "Which color do you like?",
  "Where are we?",
  "Which wells are the best?",
  "Who's on first?",
  "Cowboys wear white",
  "Wells are awesome!",
  "Whoooppppeeeeee",
  "Which Witch is Which",
  "What's going on?",
  "Well look at that!"
]

String.prototype.removePunctuation = function() {
  return this.replace(/['"`,!?:;.]/g, '')
}

String.prototype.toSnakeCase = function() {
  return this.split(' ').join('-').removePunctuation().toLowerCase()
}

searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  const searchTerm = searchBox.value.toLowerCase().trim()
  resultList.innerHTML = ''

  if (searchTerm) {
    const renderedHTML = resultsArray
      .filter(result => result.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1)
      .map(result => `
        <div class='item'>
          <a href='${result.toSnakeCase()}.html'>
            <img src='images/${result.toSnakeCase()}.png' alt='${result.removePunctuation()}' border='0'/>
          </a>
        </div>
      `)

    resultList.innerHTML = renderedHTML.length > 0 ? renderedHTML.join('') : 'No results found'
  }
})
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type='text' />
<ul id='resultList'>
</ul>
```

Here are the changes I've made to your code:

- Remove all elements in `<ul>` with `.innerHTML = ''`
- **`.trim()`** whitespace before searching.
- Iterate over `resultsArray` with **`.filter`**

  - This allows us to determine whether or not an item should be displayed while keeping everything in an array.
- Then we can use **`.map`** to generate the HTML.

  - How does that work? We are using template strings to insert the values into a string to be inserted into `.innerHTML`

You'll also have noticed that I've created `String.prototype.removePunctuation` and `String.prototype.toSnakeCase`. While I wouldn't always suggest modifying `String.prototype` it does make this code significantly more readable, in my opinion. It wouldn't be hard to convert this to regular functions.

Don't think it works? [Test out a working version here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chbchb55/95hrfo7n/28/)

FYI, in your question you ask for a `div` with an `a` that contains an `img`. The only text showing is the `alt='...'` attribute, so if you wanted to display the text of the `resultsArray` you should just use string interpolation: `${result}`

Comment: Thanks a lot  chbchb55 please guide me on  <img src='images/${result.toSnakeCase()} should the images have same names like aray items if "walt disney"  <img src='images/walt-disney.png

Comment: That's my bad what you want is `src='images/${result.toSnakeCase().toLowerCase()}.png` which will render `src='images/walt-disney.png'`

Comment: Actually, `.toSnakeCase` can handle the `.toLowerCase` as well. I'll change that in the code above.

Comment: Lastly help me if array not found, display "no results found" please write it in the code because i'm new to programming. Thanks

Comment: For this all you want is another if statement to check the length of `renderedHTML` or a ternary: `condition ? true result : false result`

Comment: I moved the `.join` into the new ternary within the return statement.

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to modify prototypes of native objects. Also, while `.innerHTML` can solve the issue, it is also generally considered a best practice to use the DOM API (`.createElement()`, `.removeChild()`, `.appendChild()`, etc.). While it's true that this approach involves more code, `.innerHTML` can become problematic when the strings are lengthy and contain many dynamic pieces. There are also security and performance issues with `.innerHTML`. The DOM API may be a bit more code, but it's much cleaner, safer, usually performs better, and easier to maintain.

Comment: While this is all true, I did put a disclaimer about the use of modifying `prototypes` in my answer. And this answer was mostly about using `.innerHTML` because in this case, to me, it is a readable, pure javascript, alternative to things like JSX or jQuery's $('<div></div>') syntax. And if you're worried about XSS it is possible to sanitize the data before using it. Also, I just [tested `.innerHTML` vs `.create | .append` with benchmark](http://jsben.ch/B8Lus) tests and `.innerHTML` is faster (I used 1000 divs to test)

Answer (score 1):

Change `resultsArray` to an array of objects with all the information needed to construct the resulting HTML.

```
var resultsArray = [
{string: "Walt Disney", url: "walt-disney.html", img: "walt-disney.png", alt: "walt disney" },
{string: "Which color do you like?", url: "which-color.html", img: "which-color.png", alt: "which color" },
...
];


if (searchTerm != "") {
    resultsArray.forEach(({string, url, img, alt} => {
        // if the array item starts with the search value AND the input box is not empty
        if(string.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm)) {

            var li = document.createElement('li'); // create an li item
            li.innerHTML = `<div class="item"><a href="${url}"><img src="images/${img}" alt="${alt}" border="0" /></a>${string}</div>`
            resultList.append(li); // add new li item to resultList ul
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to filter an array of document elements is to look at their `innerHTML` property, which is a `string` that we can use to filter based on the search term.

Here's a working solution:

**Notes:**

- To keep things simple, I have created the input resultsArray elements in the body and then grabbed them in my script using `querySelectorAll()` and then parsed them into an `Array` using `Array.prototype.slice()`.
- In the filter function, I am looking at the `innerHTML` property of this input element list array to find the matches.

```js
var searchBox = document.querySelector("input");
var resultList = document.getElementById("resultList");
// Get the results nodes list
var resultsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('#array-list>div');
// Parse the node list into an array list
var resultsArray = [].slice.call(resultsNodeList);


searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var searchTerm = searchBox.value.toLowerCase();

  // reset ul by removing all li items
  while (resultList.hasChildNodes()) {
    resultList.removeChild(resultList.lastChild);
  }

  // loop through array of sentences
  for (var i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++) { 
    // if the array item starts with the search value AND the input box is not empty
    if(searchTerm != "" && resultsArray[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
      var li = document.createElement('li'); // create an li item
      li.appendChild(resultsArray[i]); // add the sentence to the new li item
      resultList.append(li); // add new li item to resultList ul
    }
  }

  // if resultList is empty after going through loop display 'no results found'
  if (!resultList.hasChildNodes() && searchTerm != "") {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "no results found";
    resultList.append(li);
  }
});
```

```css
#array-list{
 display: none; 
}
#resultList{
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-padding-start: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="array-list">
  <div class="item"><a href="walt-disney.html"><img src="images/walt-disney.png" alt="walt disney" border="0" /></a>walt disney</div>
  <div class="item"><a href="which-color.html"><img src="images/color.png" alt="which color" border="0" /></a>which color</div>
  <div class="item"><a href="where.html"><img src="images/where.png" alt="where are we" border="0" /></a>where are we</div>
  <div class="item"><a href="best-wells.html"><img src="images/best-wells.png" alt="best wells" border="0" /></a>best wells</div>
</div>

<input type="text" placeholder="Type something to search">
<br><br>
<span>Suggestions:</span>
<ul id="resultList">

</ul>
```